# Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/library/most'

Tags: pgfkeys

I get the following error while compiling and the pdf is also not generated properly:

ERROR: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/library/most' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

The code which I compiled is available here as the accepted answer:
[LaTeX errors in Formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161601/latex-errors-in-formatting)

I am using emacs for compilation.

Comment: May be you have to install/update `tcolorbox`

Comment: If you use `\tcbuselibrary{listings,breakable}` instead of `\tcbuselibrary{most}` are you able to compile?

Comment: Saw the comment just now sir, Yes I am able to compile now with this change `\tcbuselibrary{listings,breakable}`.Sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to `tcolorbox` documentation:

[image]

It seems, `tcolorbox` is trying to load some libraries that aren't there in your system. As for this particular code, you need only `listings` and `breakable` library, you can try to load only them by

```
\tcbuselibrary{listings,breakable}
```

instead of `\tcbuselibrary{most}`.

But the better solution is to update the `tcolorbox` package to the newest version.

Comment: The last version of the folder tcolorbox (containing tcolorbox.sty) can be downloaded at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox  and is put there (on a MAC) /Library/texmf/tex/latex.